# Infinite CSS animation stops before restarting

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate an image so that it keeps spinning infinitely, because it shall represent a loading process. The image is this one if you cannot imagine what I mean:
 [image: Loading image] 
The problem is that after the animation has run it always stops for a moment. What can I do about it? Is there any way to make the transition fluent?

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Lunaetic/njdowamr/) the jsfiddle, where I replaced the image with a div

And the CSS seperately:

```
.load { /* load is a little div in this case */
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
border: 2px solid black;
animation-name: myAni;
animation-timing: linear;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-animation-name: myAni;
-webkit-animation-timing: linear;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
}

@keyframes myAni {
from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAni {
from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that animation-timing should be animation-timing-function, otherwise you get the default ease that causes the slow start and end. It was marked red in your JSFiddle.

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;-)